# Accept Training, But Planning to Leave

Tags: job-change

I work in tech, and have been with the same company long enough to retire next Spring.

I plan to do so, and change companies and work for a couple more years.

My company has been offered me a couple of 2 day training classes this fall.

Is it unethical of me to accept the classes?  Even though my plan is to leave, anything can happen between now and Spring.

Comment: One important issue would be how much it does cost that training to the company and how will affect them when you leave. If it is in-site training offered to many people and the only difference is that you are not productive for two days it is not a big an issue as if you go to a off-site, expensive course were you will be the only one from work going (so the benefits of the training will be lost when you leave). Another factor is why you want to take these courses.

Comment: We are already in the fall. In fact, we have been in the fall for more than two weeks. Can you be more precise as to when that training is actually offered?

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan Where does OP state where he lives? How do you know it's fall where he lives?

Comment: @Ajaxkevi He must be living in the Northern hemisphere because we are already in the fall. If he were living in the Southern hemisphere, he just started the Spring. In which case, the Fall is way off for him and the Spring that he is speaking off is 12 months from now. It wouldn't make too much sense for the OP to worry about the ethics of taking a one-day training session nine months from now.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan It's still not ruled out. Let's not jump too conclusions.

Comment: You've been with this company long enough to retire and can't predict how this will be perceived or held against you?

Answer (score 2):

I see three cases:

1. The training is a perk. You can turn it down as a perk and still perform your job. In which case, you should be able to turn down the training without revealing your plans.
2. The training is useful but optional. You can still turn it down without revealing your plans and lessen any downside to your refusal by requesting access to the training materials from those who underwent the training. Since the training is useful, you should be able to justify taking it to yourself, if you decide to take it.
3. The training is a pre-requisite for you to be able to accomplish some of the tasks that you will be assigned between now and the time you take retirement. In which, you have no real option but to go, your retirement plans notwithstanding.

You are the one best placed to make the determination as to which of these three cases applies to you.

The bigger ethical issue I see is that your company does not seem to be  aware as yet of your plans to retire. You should look into when to time your announcement that you are retiring to give the company enough time to physically adjust to your retirement.